# Grails run-app error in plugin

Tags: java, grails, groovy, run-app

I'm using grails `2.2.4` and `IntelliJ 13`. I installed 3 version of `Java SE` in my mac, `java6, 7, 8`. When I run my project in intelliJ, I config it with java7 and it runs.

However, when I run app in command line, I got error(almost plugins). How can I set java version when I run app in command line.

Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks

Here are errors:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: javax.mail#mail;1.4.3
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-core/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-core/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/jars/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/bundles/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-jasper/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-jasper/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/jars/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/bundles/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/jars/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/bundles/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-catalina-ant/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-catalina-ant/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/jars/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/bundles/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-juli/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-juli/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: javax.mail#mail;1.4.3: not found
        :: org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: javax.mail#mail;1.4.3
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/javax.mail/mail/ivy-1.4.3.xml
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/javax.mail/mail/jars/mail-1.4.3.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/javax.mail/mail/bundles/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/mail-1.4.3.xml
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/mail-1.4.3.xml
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/mail-1.4.3.xml
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/mail-1.4.3.pom
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/mail-1.4.3.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mail/tags/RELEASE_1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.pom
      -- artifact javax.mail#mail;1.4.3!mail.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mail/tags/RELEASE_1.4.3/grails-mail-1.4.3.jar
        module not found: org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.springframework/spring-test/ivy-3.1.0.RELEASE.xml
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.springframework/spring-test/jars/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.springframework/spring-test/bundles/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.xml
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.xml
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.xml
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-test/tags/RELEASE_3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom
      -- artifact org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE!spring-test.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-test/tags/RELEASE_3.1.0.RELEASE/grails-spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
        module not found: org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.grails/grails-plugin-tomcat/ivy-2.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.grails/grails-plugin-tomcat/jars/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.grails/grails-plugin-tomcat/bundles/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-grails-plugin-tomcat/tags/RELEASE_2.2.1/grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1!grails-plugin-tomcat.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-grails-plugin-tomcat/tags/RELEASE_2.2.1/grails-grails-plugin-tomcat-2.2.1.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/jars/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/bundles/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-core/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-core.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-core/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/jars/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/bundles/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-jasper/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-jasper.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-jasper/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/jars/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/bundles/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-log4j.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/jars/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/bundles/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-catalina-ant/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30!tomcat-catalina-ant.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-catalina-ant/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.30.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Documents/GFS/kmc-inventory/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/ivy-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/jars/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/lib/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/bundles/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/src/libs/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/dist/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      /Users/kuc/.gvm/grails/2.2.4/plugins/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-juli/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30!tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-juli/tags/RELEASE_7.0.30/grails-tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.30.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: javax.mail#mail;1.4.3: not found
        :: org.springframework#spring-test;3.1.0.RELEASE: not found
        :: org.grails#grails-plugin-tomcat;2.2.1: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.30: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-juli;7.0.30: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- javax.mail:mail:1.4.3
- org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.0.RELEASE
- org.grails:grails-plugin-tomcat:2.2.1
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.30
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.30
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.30
- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.30
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:7.0.30
```

Comment: and what error is this?

Comment: I just added errors, please take a look on that. Thanks

Comment: If you are sure problem is with java version, check "java -version" command in your console. If version is invalid set your PATH variable as described in this document: https://www.java.com/pl/download/help/path.xml

Comment: These are dependency errors. Check in your BuildConfig.groovy if your remote repositories are ok.

Comment: Here is a link how you can configure repositories http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories

Comment: Thanks guys, I knew where problem from, I used plugin directly from repo website and I command it. So it cannot update. I open that code and it works. Anyway, thank you.